# Redis zrange and zrangebyscore

Tags: redis

Are these 2 Redis commands different, except for the second having optional `LIMIT` argument?
http://redis.io/commands/zrange 
http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are different:

- `ZRANGE key start stop ...`: `start` and `stop` are zero-based **indexes** (i.e they correspond to a position of an element within the sorted set),
- `ZRANGEBYSCORE key min max ...`: `min` and `max` refer to **scores** (i.e they are used to specify a score range).

So, the first one operates by indexes while the second one (as its name implies) operates by scores. Thus they are used for different purposes.

Comment: but both return same results

Answer (score 6):

say, the sorted set is:

```
value score
tom 0
bob 1
alice 100
lucy 102
```

when you use `zrangebyscores`, and the max score is 2, the min score is 0, then, you will get `tom` and `bob`;

when you use `zrange`, and the start is 0, the stop is 2, then you will get `tom`, `bob` and `alice`.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd example 0 tom 1 bob 100 alice 102 lucy
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange example 0 2 WITHSCORES
1) "tom"
2) "0"
3) "bob"
4) "1"
5) "alice"
6) "100"
127.0.0.1:6379> zrangebyscore example 0 2 WITHSCORES
1) "tom"
2) "0"
3) "bob"
4) "1"
```

this is the key difference.